# Is detachable "speaker" a part of motherboard package? or computer case package?

Tags: motherboard, case, chassis

I have an Asus P8H77-I board and a Corsair Obsidian 250D case. Just now, I unplugged a cable that was previously plugged into the board. Its image is attached as follows:

[image]

Which of my parts does this cable belong to? (i.e. board, case, something else). I'm asking because I'm selling the board and I'm wondering if the part came originally with the board or not.

And what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's PC speaker. You connect it to your motherboard: number 9, lower right corner in the picture below; orientation doesn't really matter.

It does beep.

[The manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8H77-I/E7988_P8H77-I.pdf) of your motherboard model doesn't list PC speaker as a part of package:

> Motherboard: ASUS P8H77-I motherboard
>   Cables: 2 x Serial ATA 6.0Gb/s cables
>   Accessories: 1 x I/O shield
>   Application DVD: ASUS motherboard support DVD
>   Documentation: User Manual

The speaker may have come with the case but then it would probably be attached to it. [The installation guide](https://www.corsair.com/corsairmedia/sys_master/productcontent/250D_InstallGuide.pdf) of your case doesn't mention any PC speaker.

Such a small PC speaker with very short cables is designed to dangle freely after being connected. One can purchase it as a **standalone part**.

---

[image]

<sub>([Picture source](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8H77-I/E7988_P8H77-I.pdf)).</sub>

---

Comment: Hi thanks. So it is a part that comes with case (all the other cables that plug into that area (lower right corner) come from the case)? I'm asking because I'm selling the board and I'm wondering if the part came originally with the board or not?